# addEventListener 'click' event not recognizing click and not calling function

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, toggle, addeventlistener

EDIT: Removed all question content because I wiped my JavaScript clean and started from scratch and it worked. As far as I can tell I did not do anything different from the first time. I'm still not sure why it wasn't working before, but it is working now. See answer below for working addEventListener click/toggle event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to an event listener is the *event*. If you want the *element* the event listener is attached to, reference the `currentTarget` of the event.

```
function activateOffCanvasNav(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

If you try to do `e.classList.toggle` instead, like you're currently doing, you'll get a TypeError, since events don't have a `classList` property.

Working live demo:

```js
document.getElementById('hamburger-icon').addEventListener('click', activateOffCanvasNav);
function activateOffCanvasNav(e) {
  console.log('here')
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- small screens only -->
  <div class="small-nav-header">
    <a id="nav-toggle" href="#!">
      <div id="hamburger-icon" class="hamburger-icon">
        <div class="bar1">bar</div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! While I do realize that this is an issue that needs to be resolved, it's not the issue that I need to fix first. The function won't invoke. When I put ```console.log('activateOffCanvasNav invoked')``` as the first action in the function it doesn't get logged. So it seems that the function isn't even being called, which is what I'm trying to resolve.